# Slow query execution in an empty table. (after deleting a large amount of inserts)

Tags: oracle, indexing, performance, response

I have a table in an oracle database with 15 fields.
This table had 3500000 inserts. I deleted them all.

```
delete
from table
```

After that, whenever I execute a select statement
I get a very slow response (7 sec) even though the table is empty.
I get a normal response only in the case that I search
according to an indexed field.

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Gritem says, you need to understand high water marks etc

If you do not want to `truncate` the table now (because fresh data has been inserted), use `alter table xyz shrink space` documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2192484) for 10g

Answer (score 8):

Tom Kyte has a good explanation of this issue:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:492636200346818072

It should help you understand deletes, truncates, and high watermarks etc.

Answer (score -2):

In sql when you want to completely clear out a table, you should use truncate instead of delete. Let's say you have your table with 3.5 million rows in it and there is an index (unique identifier) on a column of bigint that increments for each row.  Truncating the table will completely clear out the table and reset the index to 0.  Delete will not clear the index and will continue at 3,500,001 when the next record is inserted.  Truncate is also much faster than delete.  Read the articles below to understand the differences.

Read this article [Read this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1080) that explains the difference between truncate and delete.  There are times to use each one.  [Here](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands) is another article from an Oracle point of view.

Comment: -1 for calling an index a 'unique identifier', mentioning indexes at all when the question doesn't, talking about `bigint` in an Oracle question, and somehow having your answer accepted

Comment: All three answers satisfied me. I accepted this answer because it made me understand more clearly what I asked and gave me 2 article links to see it in more detail. I checked all of them and found the answer more complete than the others.