# oracle query, result took long time

Tags: sql, oracle

when in issue a command

`select * from emp_table;`

the result took very long time and returns me 0 row selected, if the table has no rows in it, then why result takes so much of time ?
please help, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `emp_table` has any database locks or commit or rollback is not performed after DML statements?

Comment: Did the table contain alot of rows and are you trying the select command after a delete? You might look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408212/slow-query-execution-in-an-empty-table-after-deleting-a-large-amount-of-insert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue a query like this with no predicates and asking for all columns (`*`), Oracle has no real choice except to scan every single block in every single segment allocated to the table, even if all the blocks are empty (due, e.g. to deleted records as per Adimeus' comment).

Comment: its a question ask in an interview, I do not know in what scenario he concluded. i just what to know, what should be the correct answer to reply him.

Comment: For future reference, it would be better if you mention things like that straight away, instead of wasting people's time trying to diagnose your issue. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

So the "why" part has been answered. And the reason is the `high water mark`.

So, I would answer the "how" part. Just `TRUNCATE` the table, this will bring the high water mark to the starting point, and thus Oracle doesn't have to scan everything under high water mark.

Comment: "Just TRUNCATE the table" might not always be a good idea. On the other hand, someone who comes along and just takes your advice without considering the consequences might just deserve them...