# Strange behaviour querying former large table with just one row now

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a quite simple table in a testing environment. Yesterday it had approx. a million entries. I deleted them ( `delete from mytable; commit;`). Actually it has 1 single row.

What I don't understand (each select tested multiple times to get the execution times):

```
select * from myTable; --took 30 to 40 secs first, now constantly  9 secs
select count(*) from myTable; -- returns 1, takes  9 secs
select * from myTable where rownum < 2; --returns my single row, takes 30 millisecs
select * from tm_global_error where rownum < 3; -- returns my single row, takes  9 secs
```

Why does the full table scan take so long? Why doesn't Oracle realise, that there is only one single row?

Neither doing `analyze table myTable COMPUTE STATISTICS;` nor `analyze table myTable COMPUTE STATISTICS for all indexed columns;` did change something at all.

Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

Execution Plans:

```
select * from myTable;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                 |     1 |  2115 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| myTable         |     1 |  2115 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select count(*) from myTable;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name            | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                 |     1 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |                 |     1 |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| myTable         |     1 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


select * from myTable where rownum < 2;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                 |     1 |  2115 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| myTable         |     1 |  2115 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select * from myTable where rownum < 3;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                 |     1 |  2115 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| myTable         |     1 |  2115 | 50921   (1)| 00:10:12 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  ID         NUMBER,
  field1     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field2     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field3     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field3     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field4     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field5     NUMBER,
  field6     TIMESTAMP(6),
  field7     NUMBER,
  field8     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field9     VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)                DEFAULT 'N',
  field10    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  field11    CLOB,
  field12    DATE,
  field13    VARCHAR2(500 CHAR),
  field14    VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
  field15    DATE
)
LOB (field11) STORE AS (
  TABLESPACE  myTS
  ENABLE      STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK       8192
  RETENTION
  NOCACHE
  LOGGING
      STORAGE    (
                  INITIAL          64K
                  NEXT             1M
                  MINEXTENTS       1
                  MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                  PCTINCREASE      0
                  BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                  FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                  CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
                 ))
TABLESPACE myTS
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_IDX ON mytable
(ID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE myTS
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTable_IT
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON myTable
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:new.field12 := sysdate;
END;
/


ALTER TABLE myTable ADD (
  CONSTRAINT my_const
  CHECK (field9 in ('Y','N'))
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Comment: Added the execution plan, but I'll try the shrinking now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either(depending on Oracle edition):

- `alter table t shrink space compact;`

or

- `alter table t move`;
- plus `alter index t_ix* rebuild;` for each tables index

Another option would CTAS (create table as select):

- `create table t1 as select * from t;`
- `drop table t;`
- `alter table t1 rename to t;`
- plus re-create all the indexes on new table `T`;

All operation (except `shrink space`) are off-line.

Comment: Thank you. In my case recreating did the trick. I knew about the highwatermark in Oracle, but i thought it had "only" an influence on the amount of the used tablespace. I still don't really understand why oracle had to search the empty tablespace even after analyzing.

Answer (score 2):

The table space is still there, you have to shrink it. I had the same issue once. I found the solution here: [Slow query execution in an empty table. (after deleting a large amount of inserts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408212/slow-query-execution-in-an-empty-table-after-deleting-a-large-amount-of-insert)

In short:

```
alter table xyz shrink space
```

Comment: Thanks I think you're right, but I can't shrink  out of the box due to not enabled row movement. So I'll accept the other more detailed answer.

Comment: @evilive row movement is not so dangerous. simply use `alter table t enable/disable row movement;` before and after `shrink space`

Comment: Yes @evilive the other answer is more detailed. I'm not an expert at oracle, just shared my knowledge about the problem :).